# How can I add a static (stored) property in a class extension to make a singleton? (Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, extension-methods

I want to convert this code into Swift. The Objective-C code here is making a singleton object(if I can describe as such). I can use *dispatch_once_t* to convert it, but I want to use a more elegant way which should be similar to "*static let bundle: NSBundle!*". But "*static let bundle: NSBundle!*" is not allowed in an extension since it doesn't allow stored properties.

So is it possible to convert the code without *dispatch_once_t*?

And I faced a problem that I can not have stored properties in a class extension

@implementation NSBundle (CTFeedback)

```
+ (NSBundle *)feedbackBundle
{
    static NSBundle *bundle = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;

    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        NSBundle *classBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[CTFeedbackViewController class]];
        NSURL *bundleURL = [classBundle URLForResource:@"CTFeedback" withExtension:@"bundle"];

        if (bundleURL) {
            bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:bundleURL];
        } else {
            bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        }
    });

    return bundle;
}

@end
```

My Swift Code:

```
extension NSBundle
{
    static func feedbackBundle()-> NSBundle
    {
        static let bundle: NSBundle! //!! **Compiler Error here**

        let classBundle = NSBundle.init(forClass: CTFeedbackViewController.self)
        let bundleURL = classBundle.URLForResource("CTFeedback", withExtension: "bundle")

        if let bundleURL2 = bundleURL
        {
            bundle = NSBundle(URL: bundleURL2)
        }
        else
        {
            bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        }

        return bundle;
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**

Thanks to people's answerings. I do it like this now. I am not sure it's the best way/

```
private class FeedbackBundle
{
    static let classBundle = NSBundle.init(forClass: CTFeedbackViewController.self)
}

extension NSBundle
{
    static func feedbackBundle()-> NSBundle
    {
        let bundleURL = FeedbackBundle.classBundle.URLForResource("CTFeedback", withExtension: "bundle")
        if let bundleURL2 = bundleURL
        {
            return NSBundle(URL: bundleURL2)!
        }
        else
        {
            return NSBundle.mainBundle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error, maybe try with `self`

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, you cannot add static variables in extensions.
You can retry in the original class if accessible. Otherwise, you can modify the code like:

```
if let bundleURL2 = bundleURL
{
    return NSBundle(URL: bundleURL2)
}
else
{
    return NSBundle.mainBundle()
}
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You could always have the static var reside outside of the extension, either in a separate class or as a simple global variable (which static variables are anyway).

for example:

```
 private class FeedbackBundle
 {
   static var bundle: NSBundle!
 }

 extension NSBundle
 {
     static func feedbackBundle()-> NSBundle
     {
         let classBundle = NSBundle.init(forClass: CTFeedbackViewController.self)
         let bundleURL = classBundle.URLForResource("CTFeedback", withExtension: "bundle")

         if let bundleURL2 = bundleURL
         {
             FeedbackBundle.bundle = NSBundle(URL: bundleURL2)
         }
         else
         {
             FeedbackBundle.bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
         }

         return FeedbackBundle.bundle;
     }
 }
```

Comment: How is this any kind of singleton pattern?  You always reassign `FeedbackBundle.bundle`.

Comment: If I make "bundle" in "FeedbackBundle" a singleton, the feedbackBundle can be a singleton, too. 

I am trying beginning with "static let bundle: NSBundle! = ...".

Answer (score 0):

You can also subclass NSBundle and add this property to it.

Comment: It breaks the intention that I want to have an extension method, so I don't prefer subclass. Thank you anyway:)